# Set MSDTC Default Coordinator to Remote Host Programatically

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, msdtc

As part of Windows Server 2012 R2, there are PowerShell cmdlets to set and get the default transaction coordinator.  The `Set-DtcDefault` cmdlet allows for setting the coordinator to a remote host.

However, no such cmdlet exists for 2008r2 environments.  I've found lots of examples on how to set other MSDTC settings and properties programatically, but not this specific setting.  It's also not as simple as changing a registry key.

I've searched through WMI and couldn't find anything but performance counters for MSDTC.  Since this setting is made through a snapin, and snapin's typically interface with WMI, I figured that'd be the most likely location.

**How do you change the Default Coordinator programatically with powershell?**

Comment: Have you checked out this list of DTC Registry Key values?  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759136%28v=ws.10%29.aspx  I've dug into this a bit and agree, there doesn't seem to be a straight-forward way to do what you want.

Comment: As a matter of fact I have :)  Though I appreciate you taking the time to look into it.  The security settings are separate from the default location settings.

Comment: If you're willing to compile the class in c# (which is technically implementable with PowerShell), you can do it. However, I don't know enough c to help you. Good luck!

Comment: If someone knows where the source code to the Component Services snapin is, I'd love to get my hands on it.

Comment: Here you go, the DTC Developer's Guide from Microsoft https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679938(v=vs.85).aspx.  

Uh...good luck.

Comment: That's not the source code to the component services snapin.